# How do you stop the nodes from wobbling into place in a vis js network graph?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, networking, graph, vis.js

When a network graph is normally rendered using the vis js network, when you have lots of nodes, the nodes move around like crazy before snapping into position and resting. Is there a setting to stop this from happening and only render the final position of the nodes once all the physics has taken place?

Answer (score 1):

The option for this is named `stabilization` and the options can be seen in the documentation at https://visjs.github.io/vis-network/docs/network/physics.html.   Once enabled you can configure the `iterations` dependent on the complexity, or leave it at the default of 1000.

```js
var options = {
  physics: {
    stabilization: {
      enabled: true,
      iterations: 100
    }
  }
};
```

The best vis-network example of this is the 'loading bar' example [here](https://visjs.github.io/vis-network/examples/network/exampleApplications/loadingBar.html) ([jsfiddle](https://visjs.github.io/vis-network/examples/static/jsfiddle.5f14e5bef4f49bd9639aae45414442679daa0dbe12c125723e7e5daeb2cb73aa.html)) which has stabilization and uses the  `stabilizationProgress` event to update a loading bar. Having a loading bar prevents displaying a blank canvas whilst nodes are stabilized.

Comment: Tried enabling stabilization and increased the iterations till 3000, still the animation persist, is there any updated solution for the problem ?

Comment: @TheViralGriffin are you able to post sample code which replicates the problem you are having? I would try adjusting the various physics options are detailed in the documentation [here](https://visjs.github.io/vis-network/docs/network/physics.html), or trying the improved layout as per the documetation [here](https://visjs.github.io/vis-network/docs/network/layout.html#layout). Various options can be combined to reduce the stabilization time.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply disable the physics on the graph being rendered. It's explained in [the documentation](https://visjs.github.io/vis-network/docs/network/physics.html#).
Options would look like this:

```
const options = {
  physics: {
    enabled: false
  }
}
```

Hope it works for you